# 'Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError 10054 error in django while trying to make a post request with files

Tags: django, file, post, django-rest-framework, connection

I'm working on a django project for which I'm using an external API service. I have to send ***image files*** in the payload as well. When making a post request to the service, I'm getting this error:

**ConnectionError
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))**

Some key points are:

1. The request works perfectly fine on Postman.
2. The error appears only when I attach ***FILES*** in the payload, without which it works fine.

Comment: Without seeing any code, I'd suspect a firewall rule (depending on your scenario). Is postman running on same server as django or on a remote server?

Comment: I solved the issue. It was a really weird one and still doesn't make sense but I just removed all the headers (including Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data') other than the authorization one and it started working okay..